# How do I get Windows 7 install media if I Microsoft site rejects my key

Tags: windows-7, installation, media

Several years ago I bought a desktop with windows 7 Home Premium preinstalled. The hard drive died, so I got a new hard drive and want to do a clean install on it. I do not have an install cd.

The Microsoft recovery site will let you download a copy if you enter a product key. But it says my key is for distribution with devices pre-installed by the device manufacturer and won't let me download.

I no longer have the recovery partition, not that I would want to use it anyway. Microsoft is referring me to the device manufacturer but this isn't a branded computer, I got it from a shop near where I used to live.

Is there a legal way for someone with a valid Windows key to do a clean install on a fresh hard drive?

Comment: If you don't have the recovery discs or oem product key you will have to buy W7 system builder(oem) from eBay or Newegg, which will come with a new key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you're entering is an opk. You need the OEM or retail key, the one on the sticker. If you used a key finder, it's possible you got the opk, which Microsoft will not admit is valid.

If you can't find it, check with the shop who built your computer to verify you got a proper OEM license, and you can also ask for an installation DVD, minus a key, for much cheaper.

Comment: I got the key off the sticker on the box.

Comment: The computer itself, or the retail box copy of Windows?

Comment: A sticker on the computer. I never got a box copy of windows.

Comment: If that's the case in this scenario, Microsoft usually has a number you can call about activation issues, which would include verifying the key is normal. Depending on your country depends on the support available. Do you know the *edition* of Windows 7, and whether it's 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: Home premium 64bit

Comment: I can get you an ISO I created that is universal, but I can't leave it up for other people to snag... If you don't mind using BitTorrent, [this site](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/) has a mirror of the torrents for each Windows 7 edition. Sorry, I can't be much more help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'd need to have created a recovery/backup disk before the hard drive died on you for this to work with the same license key and even then it was 50/50 if it'd work on a different hard drive. You're likely going to have to purchase a new license key (which Microsoft isn't selling, to my knowledge, so you'll have to go 3rd party), then use the key to get the software from MS.